# Use output value from php as variable in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to take a value that a php page outputs and use it later as a variable in a calculation. Currently I am trying this:

```
var price = function() {
      $.get('gox.php')
  }


function toDol(elem) {
    var btcToDol = parseFloat(elem.value) * price || '';
    document.getElementById('dol').value = btcToDol.toFixed(2);
}

function toBtc(elem) {
    var dolToBtc = parseFloat(elem.value) / price || '';
    document.getElementById('btc').value = dolToBtc.toFixed(4);
}
```

The important part is I want the 'price' variable to equal the value gox.php outputs (e.g. 99.9999) so that I can use it later to do the math in functions 'toDol' and 'toBtc'.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the HTTP overhead is worth the number of calls to get an up-to-date BTC to USD currency rate? Why not just use a random number generator?

Answer (score 4):

```
var price = 0;
$.get('gox.php').done(function(data) {
  price = data;
});
```

Comment: Make sure you convert `data` to a number so that the math operation will work. `parseInt(data, 10)` or `Number(data)`

Comment: @Shawn31313 You don't need to convert it to a number. The `/` and `*` operators automatically (attempt to) convert its operands.

Comment: @Shawn31313 It's not a bad thing to do though, because it explicitly shows what's happening. I'd stick with `Number` (or `+` - the unary plus operator, which acts the same), because `parseFloat` and `parseInt` allows invalid characters at the end of a string and still parses. And of course, the `+` does tricky things based on the operands (like using/mixing strings in with numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
var price=$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'gox.php',
    global: false,
    async:false,
    success: function (data) {return data;}
}).responseText;
```

I always have issues with $.get and $.post

Comment: This a lot more complicated than @elzars answer.